# Problem with disposing Graphics in C# running on mono

Tags: c#, image, graphics, memory-leaks, bitmap

I am creating simple 2D game engine in C#. I am writing it on linux and I use monodevelop to compile it. I found a weird thing happens in my game loop.

```
Bitmap frame = new Bitmap((int)cam.BaseSize.Width, (int)cam.BaseSize.Height);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(frame))
{
//There is nothing inside it for now
}
return frame;
```

Bitmap is disposed after returning it, but my memory is slowly running out. I realized that when I comment all lines with graphics and leave creating bitmap and return all my code works perfectly. Is it mono bug or what is happening here?

Mono version: 6.6.0.166
.NET version: 4.7.2

Comment: Is there a possibility to reuse the `frame` bitmap?

Comment: Use a memory profiler

Comment: I tried to dispose bitmap before returning it and app runs without any NullReferenceException, but I called FillRectangle method in my graphics to paint something and displayed bitmap is not painted so it looks like bitmap is disposed but I can still access it

Comment: You need to dispose both the bitmap and the `Graphics` object, and of course do so only when you are done with them. Since you are returning the `frame` object, the code that receives it is the owner and is responsible for disposing it. In other words, the bug is elsewhere in your program, in the part you didn't bother to show. I will also suggest that creating a _new_ bitmap object with every frame of the game loop is a terrible idea. Even if it works, it's a ton of overhead for no good reason...allocate the frame buffer once and draw into as needed.

Comment: I thought that bug is somwhere else but when i am not creating graphics object there program runs perfectly

Comment: I get the same issue, Net6 on Linux/Docker.  
Even if you immediately dispose bitmap in this sample, the memory will not be cleared and will grow.
But if you comment out command "Graphics.FromImage()", then the problem disappears.
It looks like "Graphics.Dispose()" doesn't work correctly on Linux.